# Struckthrough Japanese text doesn't get wrapped in a lang="ja" span

Tags: bug, status-completed, furigana

Struckthrough text (e.g. `<s>日本</s>` → <s>日本</s>) doesn't get wrapped in the same `<span lang="ja">` tags that wrap other Japanese text on this site. This makes the text look slightly uglier than necessary.

[image: struckthrough]

A minor bug; perhaps worth fixing next time someone is making changes to the furigana/helper script.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to have been fixed in the last update. Now we have

> 日本語
> <s>日本語</s>
>
> [image: struck through Japanese text]